# Django Many to Many matching multiple criteria

Tags: django

I have multiple related models. A given `Work` object has `Crew` that are defined by their `Person` and/or `Company` and their given `Role`. I want to build an efficient query that returns all projects (distinct) for a given `Crew` instance with a given `Role`...

```
class Work(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Crew(models.Model(models.Model):
    work=models.ForeignKey(Work)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Company)
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role)
```

Individual records all have a `slug` field for identification. (`Person`, `Company`, `Role`)

I don't have a problem querying `Person` or `Company` for a given `Work` but adding the `Role` is where I'm lost.

Eg. `works = works.filter(crew__person__slug=person_slug).distinct()` is easy enough

Do I use a Q object?

Errr.... maybe it's as easy as `works = works.filter(crew__person__slug=person_slug,crew__role__slug=role_slug).distinct()`

> I think OP just answered his own question...

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly multiple constraints against a m2m field in the same `filter` clause all have to match the same related object so your updated example looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, I answered my own question in the question gibberish but it's helpful nonetheless. I didn't use a Q object.

```
works = works.filter(crew__person__slug=person_slug,crew__role__slug=role_slug).distinct()
```